# NextJs getStaticProps vs direct import local image asset

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Say if I have a static image asset that I want to use as the hero image for the home page. What would be the correct way of importing it? Does it make a difference between a direct import:

```
import hero from "/public/assets/hero.jpg"

export default function Home(){
return(
    <>
     <Image src={hero}/>
    </>
 )}
```

vs import it and then supply the data via getStaticProps:

```
import hero from "/public/assets/hero.jpg"

export default function Home({data}){
return(
    <>
     <Image src={data}/>
    </>
 )}


export const getStaticProps = async(()=>{
  props: {
   data: hero
  }
})
```

I'm trying to understand what difference it makes with the above use case, or if there is no difference at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing this, I see no difference. In both cases the URL of the image is what is being passed around, and the browser will request the image by URL the exact same way.

I used a small-ish image (2K) to test which could have been theoretically base-64 encoded to be inlined in the source in the second case, but this didn't happen, at least not automatically.